# I can't rewind the animation in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, trim, stroke

I animated on Trim function, but after the animation is complete, I want the X mark to be drawn again. However, the X mark is not drawn again. What am I missing?

[image]

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var winningPlayer: UIBezierPath = .none

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ShapeView(bezier: .playerX, pathBounds: playerBounds)
                    .trim(from: 0, to: self.Xamount ? 1 : 0)
                    .stroke()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("\(playerXScore)")
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                Spacer()
                Text("\(playerOScore)")
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                ShapeView(bezier: .playerO, pathBounds: playerBounds)
                    .trim(from: 0, to: self.Oamount ? 1 : 0)
                    .stroke()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: winningPlayer, perform: { value in
            if value == .playerX {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatCount(1)) {
                    self.Xamount.toggle()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.animation` also repeatCount should be 2:

also in your question body you said ***drawn again*** if you want just draw again then `autoreverses: false` but in your question title you said ***rewind*** in that case `autoreverses: true`

---

```
.animation(Xamount ? Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).repeatCount(1, autoreverses: false) : .none, value: Xamount)
.animation(Oamount ? Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).repeatCount(1, autoreverses: false) : .none, value: Oamount)
.onChange(of: winningPlayer, perform: { value in
    
    if value == .playerX {
        
        self.Xamount.toggle()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(100)) { Xamount = true }
        
    }
    else {
        
        self.Oamount.toggle()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(100)) { Oamount = true }
        
    }
    
})
```

Comment: No sir. Same problem. This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

WithAnimation I am making the Amount variables true again.

[image]

```
.animation(winningPlayer == .playerX ? Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).repeatCount(1, autoreverses: false) : .none, value: Xamount)
            .animation(winningPlayer == .playerO ? Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).repeatCount(1, autoreverses: false) : .none, value: Oamount)
            .onChange(of: winningPlayer, perform: { value in
                if value == .playerX {
                    self.Xamount.toggle()
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(1)) {
                        self.Xamount = true
                    }
                } else {
                    self.Oamount.toggle()
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(1)) {
                        self.Oamount = true
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Look my updated answer, that is better I think, with less code.